# \only<1> with tikzpicture throws Illegal parameter number error. What to do?

Tags: tikz-pgf, only

This is MWE :

```
\begin{frame}
\only<1>{
   \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,
box/.style = {rounded corners, fill=####1}]
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}
```

It works without error when I either remove the \only<1> or tikz block. Also changing ####1 to #1 is ineffective.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: What is the fill color you want? Both `####1` and `#1` are not valid outside a macro definition; try something like `cyan`. And please, do what @hpekristiansen suggest --- your code is impossible to debug in this state.